# admin page issues - Cloudflare with Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have configured a Magento 2.0.7 website with Cloudflare. The issue is some admin pages are not loading correctly. For example, catalog management page cannot load products list, user management page cannot load user list. Other admin pages work OK. 
When I used it as static ip ex (xx.xx.xx.xx) it really work but not in subdomain
I created page rules with admin url but nothing changes.
Please can you help me ?

Comment: any errors in logs or browser?

Comment: I got this message : Uncaught Error: Module name "mage/utils/arrays" has not been loaded yet for context: _
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same issue as you where page and block lists would not load, the Stores->configuration CSS was not properly displaying, and there were other display issues.

The previous answer asked you to disable JS Minification and two other paid features Rocketloader and Mirage ( I am on the free plan so I don't use either).  This did not solve my issue.

`TL;DR`
This was solved by disabling ALL minification in the Cloudflare dashboard under the "Speed" Tab.
[image: Disable All Auto Minification]
After saving, all display issues were resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Please disable the following in the CloudFlare dashboard:

- Disable JS minification
- Disable RocketLoader
- Disable Mirage

That should resolve any conflicts; if not, please let me know.

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work...Have you installed Cloudflare with Magento2 ?

Comment: mjsa, all your recommandation have already done but nothing changes...It doesn't work yet.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is to late for answering but you can do this step

You can bypass the clodflare for admin, so you can do steps shown in their blog

go to

to Page Rules by going to: `settings->Page Rules`.

and

You can make rules more flexible by including wildcards with the * character. For example, if you wanted the pattern to match all four of the above URLs, you could use a pattern like:

```
*example.com/admin*
```

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172316-How-do-I-exclude-a-specific-URL-from-CloudFlare-s-caching-